# Get previous item from iterable JS object?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iteration

Is it possible get the previous item from iterable JS object?

where `tokens` is an iterable object (not array).

```
for (let token of tokens) {
  //token === the current token
  //const last_token = ???
}
```

Comment: Make a `let last;` variable and keep the previous item there?

Comment: if it's an object you can use `.entries()`, `.keys()` or `.values()` to iterate as an array with index passed.

Comment: At each iteration save the current value, which in the next iteration will be used as the previous one

Answer (score 0):

what about just storing the token at the end of the loop body? First iteration is undefined or null or whatever since there is no previous.

```
let prev = undefined;
for (let token of tokens) {
    //do whatever it is you're doing
    prev = token;
}
```